# Getting AddressSanitizer error when I am trying to run my code

Tags: c++, arrays, data-structures

This is a leet code problem which I am trying to solve https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/
Below is the code which is running on my ide but i am not able to run this code. There it is showing AddressSanitizer error. Please help me to resolve this problem

```
    class Solution 
{
  public:
    int maxArea(vector<int>& height) 
    {
        int n=height.size(),product=1;
        int i=0,j=n-1;
        while(i<j)
        {
            int x=(height[i]<height[j])?height[i]:height[j];
            int y=j-i;
            int p=x*y;
            if(product<p)
                product=p;
            while(height[i]<=height[j])
                i++;
            while(height[i]>height[j])
                j--;
        }
        return product;
    }
};
```

> =================================================================
> ==31==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x606000000060 at pc 0x0000003760a2 bp 0x7ffc947d7160 sp
> 0x7ffc947d7158 READ of size 4 at 0x606000000060 thread T0
> #3 0x7f4235b5f0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2) 0x606000000060 is located 0 bytes to the right of 64-byte region
> [0x606000000020,0x606000000060) allocated by thread T0 here:
> #10 0x7f4235b5f0b2  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x270b2) Shadow bytes around the buggy address:   0x0c0c7fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   0x0c0c7fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   0x0c0c7fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   0x0c0c7fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00   0x0c0c7fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
> =>0x0c0c7fff8000: fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa   0x0c0c7fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c0c7fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c0c7fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c0c7fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
> 0x0c0c7fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa

Comment: When you are doing that for example: `while(height[i]<=height[j]) i++;` you might have an out-of-band access. You must check that `i < n`. Same with `j >= 0` for following lines.

Comment: @Damien Thanks for replying. Can you please tell me what changes should I make in my code so that I can avoid this out of bound access as it is still not working when I am changing the statement of while loop like this: while((i<j)&&(i<n)&&(j>=0))

Comment: Do you always have the addressSanitizer error?

Comment: Your modification doesn't solve the fact that here `while(height[i]<=height[j]) i++;` you may have an out-of-band access. You should try `while((i<n)&&(height[i]<=height[j])) i++;`. About same for `j` in the next `while(...)`

Comment: Thanks a lot, @Damien for helping me.